# Crystal Report Not Defined

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report, defined

I am trying to do a vb.net application from scratch. But I have a problem defining the crystal report files: [image]

The target framework is the .Net Framework4.

I have done one project before and everything is working perfectly. Then I faced this problem and temporary solved it by copying the working project and modify it. But this is not the best way for doing it. I want to be able to do it as a new project and include the needed files.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add Crystal Report References on your project..

Project > Add Reference > your crystal report references.

also, don't forget to add this on your `app.config` file

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```

Comment: There are so many references for crystal report! Which ones of these I should add?

Comment: find all that you just imported on the code.. it should be there, under the .NET tab

Comment: All right, all I did is thee up comment. Thank you Mr. Codemunkeee.